# opening HTML file using express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('sys');

var app = express();
    app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('/views/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Express server started');
```

I don't want to use the template engine jade. How can i open a simple index.html page which resides inside my view folder. The server is getting started, but it seems i am not able to load the index.html page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using express 3.0.0rc3, the following works:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Or

```
app.set("view options", {layout: false});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

So your final code would look like this.

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('sys');

var app = express();
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.set("view options", {layout: false});
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('/views/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Express server started');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now, instead of using res.send(), use res.sendfile('index.html')

Answer (score 0):

Using express v4.7.1 and without using the template engine jade, this works fine.

In the latest releases, the sendfile() has been changed to sendFile().

For a file path, the server tries to find the path of the file from the root directory, so it gets mandatory to specify either the entire path or use the '_dirname', else always the file not found error will be faced.

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'))

});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Express server started');
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let express=require('express');
let app=express();


app.get( '/', (req,res)=>{
res.sendFile(__ dirname + "/my.txt");

})
app.listen(4000);
```

Try this. It will work fine.